# Remove audio from video file with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I strip the audio track out of a video file with FFmpeg?

Answer (score 766, accepted):

You remove audio by using the `-an` flag:

```bsh
input_file=example.mkv
output_file=example-nosound.mkv

ffmpeg -i $input_file -c copy -an $output_file
```

This ffmpeg flag is documented [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options).

Comment: I'm a `bash` and `ffmpeg` newbie but I put this answer together with some other pieces to create
`function ffsilent { ffmpeg -i $1 -c copy -an "$1-nosound.${1#*.}" }`
which you can use in your profile to quickly create a silent version of any video file.

Comment: @Aaron nice, but should be `function ffsilent { ffmpeg -i "$1" -c copy -an "${1%.*}-nosound.${1#*.}" }` or you'll end up with "file.mp4-nosound.mp4" when using it on "file.mp4".

Comment: This doesn't carry over GPS coordinates.

Comment: Using `-c copy -an` works on most video files but it won't strip audio from SWF (Shockwave Flash) files. The solution is to shorten it to just `-an` then it works.

Comment: Are you sure that this avoids re-encoding the video?

Comment: @rlittles Yes, `-c copy` always avoids re-encoding, If it can't it will fail with an error.

Comment: Be sure to put the `-an` flag before `$output_file`

Answer (score 138):

You probably don't want to reencode the video (a slow and lossy process), so try:

```bsh
input_file=example.mkv
output_file=example-nosound.mkv

ffmpeg -i $input_file -vcodec copy -an $output_file
```

(n.b. some Linux distributions now come with the [avconv fork of ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv))

Comment: This didn't make any difference to me compared to the accepted solution.

Comment: vcodec is an alias for `-c:v`, so specifically it'd copy the video stream only. The only data you're preventing with this would be subtitles, metadata, etc from what I can see.

Comment: In other words, this solution can conceivably lose more information than the accepted solution.

Comment: We can call this "only video" solution :+1:

Comment: I agree: This here is the "copy video only" solution, whereas the accepted answer is the "copy everything but audio" solution.

Answer (score 12):

```
avconv -i [input_file] -vcodec copy -an [output_file]
```

If you cannot install `ffmpeg` because of existing of `avconv` try that .

Answer (score 3):

I put together a short code snippet that automates the process of removing audio from videos files for a whole directory that contains video files:

```
FILES=/{videos_dir}/*
output_dir=/{no_audio_dir}
for input_file in $FILES
do
  file_name=$(basename $input_file)
  output_file="$output_dir/$file_name"
  ffmpeg -i $input_file -c copy -an $output_file
done
```

I hope this one helps!

Comment: Out of interest, how would I use this snippet when there are spaces in the video dir (and output dir)?

Comment: @PaulSkinner adding quotes should be enough eg: `file_name=$(basename "$input_file")`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `-map` option of `ffmpeg` to get better control on what exactly will be put into the final video container.

Lets say for example that your video file `my_video.mp4` is composed this way:

```bash
Input #0
  Stream #0:0 Video: h264
  Stream #0:1 Audio: English
  Stream #0:2 Audio: German
  Stream #0:3 Audio: Japanese
  Stream #0:4 Audio: Spanish
  Stream #0:5 Audio: Italian
```

To remove **all** audio tracks (like the `-an` option does):

```bash
ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:a -c copy my_video.noaudio.mp4`
```

`-map 0` grabs the entire input (videos, audios, subtitles, metadata, chapters, etc.).
`-map -0:a` **removes all audio tracks** from input 0 (notice the `-` sign).
`-c copy` copies as it is without re-encoding.

To remove the **Japanese** and **Spanish** tracks:

```bash
ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:3 -map -0:4 -c copy my_video.nojap.noesp.mp4`
```

`-map -0:3` removes the 3rd track from input 0, which is the Japanese audio.
`-map -0:4` removes the 4rd track from input 0, which is the Spanish audio.

To remove all audio tracks but **Italian**:

```bash
ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:a -map 0:5 -c copy my_video.ita.mp4`
```

`-map -0:a` removes all audio tracks from input 0.
`-map 0:5` inserts the 5th track from input 0, which is the Italian audio (notice NO `-` sign in this case).

---

This is also very useful also when dealing with more than one file.
For example when:

- grabbing audio from one file
- audio tracks from another one
- subtitles and metadata from a third one

Answer (score -2):

I have taken @apolak's answer and turned it in to a recursive loop for all folders underneath the input folder. It will retain the directory layout of the input folder, and you can set a max-depth for it to recurse through. The output directory must not be a child of the input directory or it will error, to stop accidental infinite recursion. It should also be fine with spaces in filenames and paths.

NOTE: all files within the input directory will be attempted to be processed, so make sure they're all video files.

```
#!/bin/bash

process_files() {
    local current_dir="$1"
    local output_dir="$2"
    local max_depth="$3"
    local depth="${4:-0}" # Set default value of 0 if $4 is not set
    if [ "$depth" -gt "$max_depth" ]; then
        return
    fi
    # Check if output directory is a subdirectory of the input directory and error
    # This should stop accidental recursive loops
    if [[ "$output_dir" == "$current_dir"* ]]; then
        echo "Error: Output directory is a subdirectory of the input directory"
        exit 1
    fi
    mkdir -p "$output_dir"
    for input_file in "$current_dir"/*
    do
        if [ -d "$input_file" ]; then
            # If the input file is a directory, recurse into it
            process_files "$input_file" "$output_dir/$(basename "$input_file")" "$max_depth" "$((depth+1))"
        elif [ -f "$input_file" ]; then
            # If the input file is a regular file, process it
            local file_name=$(basename "$input_file")
            local output_file="$output_dir/$file_name"
            ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -c copy -an "$output_file"
        fi
    done
}

# Call function with input and output directories and maximum depth
process_files "/Volumes/Storage/ORIGINAL" "/Volumes/Storage/MUTED" 2 # Set the maximum recursion depth to 2
```