# How to remove audio from multiple videos on a Mac

Tags: mac, video, imovie

Is there a way to remove the audio from multiple video files on a Mac? Or would the only possibility be to do it manually per file using e.g. iMovie?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with `ffmpeg`.  This question has been asked and answered before:

[Remove audio from video file with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg)